# References for Langlands classification

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, langlands-conjectures, geometric-langlands

I kindly ask about some references concerning the representation theory of the Langlands dual of a compact Lie group, and how it relates to things related to the original compact Lie group.

My background: I know some basic facts about Lie groups/algebras, such as their root systems, Weyl groups etc. I am not familiar yet with the Langlands program, and related things. I am mostly interested for now in working over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Edit 1: after some research, I realize that what I want is a reference on the Langlands classification, done by Langlands himself. So I will start by reading that article by Langlands ("On the classification of irreducible representations of real algebraic groups").

Edit 2: I found some introductory notes on endoscopy by J-P Labesse, which look very promising to me! http://www.math.utah.edu/~ptrapa/src2006/labesse.pdf

Edit 3: Knapp's article, suggested by Desiderius Severus, is indeed a really good introduction to the Langlands classification, which is part of the local Langlands program in the Archimedean case. In some of my comments, one can see that I was confused between the Langlands classification, and the geometric Satake isomorphism, which plays a role in the Geometric Langlands program. I apologize for this confusion. It took me some time to get used to some of the jargon of the Langlands program (and even now, I cannot claim to have mastered the jargon, but I have improved a little).

Comment: You might be interested in the geometric Satake theorem, which expresses the representation theory of $G^\vee$ in terms of sheaves on the affine Grassmannian for $G$. See [Zhu's notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05593) for the full story.

Comment: @ArunDebray, thank you. The subject is tough but interesting.

Comment: @Malkoun:  Probably you should add one or two tags, such as 'lie-groups' and 'rt.representation-theory'.    The Langlands program is especially concerned with connecting such subjects to number theory.    You might take a look at somewhat older contributions (the two Bulletin articles being freely available online): https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1990371 and http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1984-10-02/S0273-0979-1984-15237-6, /https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2823020

Comment: @Jim Humphreys, thank you so much for these references. I have plenty to read now.

Comment: @JimHumphreys, Prof. Humphreys, I love the topic, and particularly the links to Number Theory. In my opinion, the reciprocity theorems are extremely beautiful. But, I would like to get faster to what I want specifically, meaning while avoiding "adèles" and "idèles", for the time being (only). Do you happen to know of a specific reference on the Langlands classification theorem? I started reading a paper by Langlands, but I am missing some definitions.

Comment: @Malkoun:  The Langlands classification of representations of real groups is fairly complicated, as I recall, and has lots of notation even while avoiding other local fields.    That said, I'm unsure which paper of Langlands you are reading.    But there is much to read in the webpage at IAS devoted to his work: see especially 2 in the list, with the 79 page PDF version of an older basic paper of his: http://publications.ias.edu/rpl   I'm not sure what people currently rely on, but Knapp is also a helpful guide.

Comment: @JimHumphreys I am actually reading a very lucid paper by Benedict Gross on the Satake isomorphism. I am also curious about the list of known theorems which are similar to the Satake isomorphism. I may ask this in another post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first source in which I really discovered quite explicitly the archimedean local Langlands classification is in [this](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~aknapp/pdf-files/motives.pdf) beautiful article of Knapp, reviewing it in some pages. Moreover, it has the appeal to give a short historical motivation, to deal with the $SL_2$ case, and then to turn to the general one in an explicit manner.

> A. Knapp, *The Local Langlands Correspondence: The Archimedean Case*,
>   Proc. Symp. Pure Math, Volume 55 (1994), Part II

Comment: It sounds great, thank you so much! I like how Prof. Knapp writes, so this will probably explain what I want in a very clear and concise way. Thank you.